# Why is my memcpy from a vector of bytes into aligned memory not actually copying anything?

Tags: c++, simd, memory-alignment

```
    __m128i* pData = reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(
        _aligned_malloc(
            128,
            16));

    std::vector<byte> sectorBytes = dataSet.GetSectorBytes(index);

    index &= 0xfff;

    memcpy(pData, &sectorBytes[index], 128);
```

as you can see, I'm trying to copy 128 bytes from sectorBytes (which has no guarantees of 16-byte-alignment) into pData, which does.  Unfortunately, after setting a breakpoint to check, I've found that while sectorBytes has exactly what I'd anticipated it to have, pData[0] through pData[7] contain only zeroes... so nothing is actually getting copied.

I don't understand why nothing's being copied... why is this happening?

Of course, the larger task I'm trying to accomplish is taking 128 bytes from a file at a specified offset, and then performing _mm_xor_si128() on them without an access violation popping up from trying to do simd operations on data that isn't 16-byte-aligned.  In the interest of facilitating that discussion, here's GetSectorBytes():

```
std::vector<byte> GetSectorBytes(
    _In_ const uint32_t index) const throw()
{
    std::vector<byte> buffer(0x1000);

    int indexOuter = index & 0xfffff000;

    _OVERLAPPED positionalData;
    positionalData.Offset = indexOuter;
    positionalData.OffsetHigh = 0;
    positionalData.hEvent = 0;

    ReadFile(
        hMappedFile,
        &buffer[0],
        0x1000,
        NULL,
        &positionalData);

    return buffer;
}
```

hMappedFile was created with CreateFile2 with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag set.

Comment: The second parameter to `memcpy()` should probably be `&sectorBytes[0]`.

Comment: I really do want the data at sectorBytes[index], but in the interest of seeing if that made a difference, I tried it at 0.  Still nothing being copied (the 128 bytes starting at 0 are nonzero as well).

Comment: Use `_mm_loadu_si128` on the original data instead of wasting cycles copying it into an aligned buffer.  Or better, change your file-read function to read into an aligned buffer.  (Getting aligned allocation for `std::vector` is annoyingly complex, though.)

Comment: Technically it's undefined behaviour to use malloc'd space as if it contained objects -- you need to use `new` to create objects.  But I wasn't aware of any C++ compilers that did not permit this usage so it might be a red herring.

Comment: It would improve the question to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), outputting to stdout, so that others can reproduce the unxpected output

Comment: Using _mm_loadu_si128 takes care of the problem (i.e. , so the main goal is addressed.  I'm going to toy with the _aligned_malloc a bit to see if that answers the failed memcpy.